# How to properly use .SelectedIndex property for listbox using arrays

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Module Inv
    Public Item(4) as String
End Module

Private Sub Inventory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Inventory.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Inventory.SelectedIndex.ToString(Item(0)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Item Selected!")
        playerDMG *= 3
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Item(0) = "Plasma"
    for add = 0 to 0 
    inventory.items.add(item(add))
End Sub
```

What I want is that if I click that button it adds Item(0) to the listbox, and if I click on the item in the listbox it will triple playerDMG.
Problem here is that it is telling me I can't convert "Plasma Gun" to type 'Boolean'
What's going wrong here? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The `SelectedIndex` is the index of the `SelectedItem`. If you select the first item, `SelectedIndex` will be 0.  If you select the Second item, `SelectedIndex` will be 1.  Etc.  With that in mind, how does `Inventory.SelectedIndex.ToString(Item(0))` make any sense?  What is that line actually intended to achieve?

Comment: Actually now that I know what selectedIndex really does, I'll probably just use this in some other way. What I wanted to achieve with `Inventory.SelectedIndex.ToString(Item(0))` was that if I clicked it it will increase my playerDMG value but clearly I didn't understand what selectedIndex actually did. The array was supposed to work somehow

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do something like this:

```
If Inventory.SelectedItem.ToString() = Item(0) Then ...
```

Alternatively, you could use `SelectedValue` I guess, but in order for that to work you'd need to use `DataSource` property of combobox.